# Powershell - Getting Distribution Lists that have sender Restrictions

Tags: powershell, email, export-to-csv

We have a distribution list (called "TopGroup", for example) that has sub-DLs inside it, as well as normal personal user email accounts alongside those nested DLs. For some reason, only the individual accounts are receiving any mail sent to MasterDL. Any members inside the sub-DLs do not receive anything sent to MasterDL in their inbox. then I have noticed there is restriction (to only allow specific users sending message to specific distribution groups.) on some sub-DLs.BTW I have been using Exchange Server 2013.

script regarding this? What we are looking for is a PowerShell script that can

1 - Identify all nested groups

2 - Identify on each TOP DL check for 2nd layer DL

2 - Identify 2nd layer DL Distribution Lists that have sender Restrictions and get list

3 - Report them and take output to CSV

4 - optional-  notify user and manager and IT group via email

it would be output like below :

```
ParentGroupName    SubDL1  Restriction     SubDL2     Restriction       .... so on

Group              Group1  GroupA,GroupB   Group2     GroupA,GroupB,Group
```

Here is my script so far :

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*'" -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com" | Select SamAccountName
    Foreach ($g in $groups)
    {
      $member = Get-ADGroupMember $g | ?{$_.ObjectClass -eq "Group"} | Select Name,SamAccountName
      foreach ($sg in $member)
      {
      $sgname = $sg.name
      Write-Host $sgname -foregroundcolor "magenta" -backgroundcolor "yellow"
      $dg = Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "$sgname"

      if ($dg.AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers.count -ne 0){

      Write-Host "$($dg.Name) has mail attribute set" -ForegroundColor Green
     Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -filter {AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers -ne $null} | select-object Name,@{Name="AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers";Expression={[string]::join(";",($_.AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers| foreach {$_.name}) )}}
  }
      }

    elseif($dg.AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers.count -eq 0){
    Write-Host "$($dg.Name) has no mail attribute set" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    }

       }

    }
```

Error message :

```
#Test_groupA has mail attribute set Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "@{SamAccountName=test}" to type  "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{SamAccountName=test}" value of  type "Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup"." At line:9 char:31
+   $member = Get-ADGroupMember $g | ?{$_.ObjectClass -eq "Group"} | Select Name,S ...
+                               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is the script not doing now that you need help with? All you said was here it is

Comment: if and else/if condition  doesn't work as expected. Also as I mentioned above I need to export CSV file.

Comment: How doesn't it work as expected? Can you post how exactly your results don't align with what you're looking for, including any error messages, and steps you have taken to try to solve the problem?

Comment: Now , I am checking the count of AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers  instead of check whether it is null. So no issue for if / else statement. My other question is : I want to pull the complete list of the AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers field within if statement. Am I correct? I have attached my error message